# Defining a function pointer of an unspecified namespace

Tags: c++, function, pointers, namespaces, global

I'm making a simple developer console for a game I'm working on with a friend of mine. I'm  working on binding functions to the console, so I have an std::map containing a string to hold the name we'll call it by in the console, and my own defined MFP type which is a function pointer that returns a sf::String (we're using SFML and sf is the SFML namespace) and takes an sf::String as a parameter. All console functions take a sf::String and return an sf::String.

Here's what the code in question looks like (is not ALL the code):

```
#include <SFML/System/String.hpp>
using namespace sf;

#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class CConsole
{
public:
    typedef sf::String (*MFP)(sf::String value);    //function pointer type

    void bindFunction(string name, MFP func);    //binds a function
    void unbindFunction(string name);    //unbinds desired function
private:
    map <string, MFP> functions;
}
```

Now this is all fine and dandy so long as the functions we're trying to bind to the console are of the global namespace. But this won't do. It'll be too inefficient to constantly be making global wrapper functions for every single nested function we want to bind to the console.

Is it at all possible to make 'MFP' accept function pointers of all namespaces? For example, to get the fallowing code to work perfectly?

```
#include "console.h"    //code shown above

//Let's also pretend CConsole has an sf::String(sf::String value) method called consoleFunc that returns "Hello from the CConsole namespace!"

sf::String globalFunc(sf::String value)
{
     return "Hello from the global namespace!";
}

int main()
{
    CConsole console;
    console->bindFunction("global", globalFunc);
    console->bindFunction("CConsole", CConsole::consoleFunc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would use std::function .

Comment: Any free function can bind too a function pointer of type MFP, as long as it has correct signature. See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e1a7907a2c4ab2fb7862f5f94afad68a-d77f64e4484f751719e92fe5e8b5b11c). Namespaces don't hinder you in any way here. Maybe you're confusing namespaces and class scope. It's true that you can't bind member functions to normal function pointers.

Comment: youre right. i am confusing class scopes and namespaces. how would I get bindFunction() to work with class methods?

Comment: Suggestion: Pass as `const std::string&`

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can call `bindFunction` on any non-member function, or a static member function of any class. You cannot `bindFunction` with a non-static member, as they have a different type.